# Desired instances VS. Scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm trying to understand how Scaling Policy and Desired Instances fit with each other.

Suggest I'm having the following scenario.

- Min: 0
- Max:4
- ***Desired Instances:*** 2

Scaling Policy:

- Scale out: When CPU avg > 60%
- Scale in: When CPU avg < 20%

Initial state: 2 instances are up.

**Step one:**

Increasing the CPU of both instance to average of 90%.

**Step two occurs:**

Auto Scaling increases the number of instances to 3.

**Step three:**

Keeping the average CPU of the machines around 40%, so that no scale out or scale in will trigger.

**Step four:**

Now we have three instance, no scale out, or in trigger, but the desired instances is two. What rule should "win"?

The desired instances of 2 (one instance will be removed)?

Or the scaling policy (nothing should change, keep the 3 instances up)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto Scaling will always try to give you the number of instances indicated by the **Desired Capacity**.

For example, when starting an auto scaling group with `Desired Capacity = 2`, auto scaling will launch 2 instances. Changing the Desired Capacity to 3 would then cause auto scaling to launch 1 additional instance (total = 3).

**Scaling Policies** tell auto scaling to **change the Desired Capacity**.

For example, an Amazon CloudWatch alarm triggered by CPU exceeding a given threshold could be configured to **trigger a Scaling Policy**. The Scaling Policy could be configured with a rule of **Add 1 instance**, which would cause the Desired Capacity to increment by 1. (Note: Desired Capacity will always stay within the boundaries of the Min and Max, so a scaling policy might not actually change the Desired Capacity.)

In your example **Step 1 caused a CloudWatch alarm to trigger**, which executed a scaling policy that increased Desired Capacity from 2 to 3. There are no competing rules to "win".

[Scaling adjustment types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#as-scaling-adjustment) can be of: `ChangeInCapacity`, `ExactCapacity` and `PercentChangeInCapacity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually set the desired value, the auto scaling group (almost) instantly scales (in/out) to that number.